# How to create custom signal in java-gnome?

Tags: java, gtk3

I am trying to create custom signal in `java-gnome` in my `GTK+3` application but I can't.

```
import org.gnome.gtk.CheckButton;

public class MyCheckButton extends CheckButton {

    // how can I add a cutom signal for this class
    // fos example: the signal that has "my-signal" name.
}
```

How can I do it?

I can do it in python

```
class MyCheckButton(Gtk.CheckButton):
    __gsignals__ = {
        'my_signal': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None,
                      (int,))}
abc = MyCheckButton()
abc.connect("my-signal", print)
abc.emit("my-signal", 543)
```

I've searched on the internet but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the problem you have, explaining where you want to add a custom signal.

Comment: @Progman, I edited my question you can examine again.

Comment: I guess that must be implemented Button.Clicked, that is described in http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/gtk/Button.Clicked.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no similar way in Java (based on the fact that there is no similar structure in the source code).

But you can implement your own handler by:

- Define the handler interface (#1)
- Add a connect method (#2, #3)
- Add an emit method (#4)

Sample code:

```
public class MyCheckButton extends CheckButton {

    // ...

    private MySignalHandler handler; // #2

    public interface MySignalHandler {  // #1
        public void onMySignal(int value);
    }

    public void connect(MySignalHandler handler) {  // #3
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void emitMySignal(int value) {  // #4
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler.onMySignal(value);
    }

}
```

And then you can connect and emit in the same way as the other events.

```
MyCheckButton a = new MyCheckButton();

a.connect(new MyCheckButton.MySignalHandler() {
  public void onMySignal(int value) {
    System.out.println(value);
  }
});

a.emitMySignal(10);
```

The built-in `Button` uses something similar to define the click event by adding the `connect(Clicked handler)` and `emitClicked()` ([source code](https://github.com/afcowie/java-gnome/blob/master/src/bindings/org/gnome/gtk/Button.java#L339))